# rxnetty connection pool throws PoolExhaustedException

Tags: exception, connection, netty, pool, rx-netty

When I use rxnetty connection pool, I got following errors

> io.reactivex.netty.client.PoolExhaustedException at
>   io.reactivex.netty.client.ConnectionPoolImpl$1.call(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:147)
>   at
>   io.reactivex.netty.client.ConnectionPoolImpl$1.call(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:117)

The test calls are sequential, one finished, then starts another, the pool max is 1. In the second call, it throws above exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not http client I am using, but tcp. Seems I have to close ObservableConnection by myself, which i did in doOnComplete. (1) I do not know whether that is the correct place. (2) Should rxnetty close it if it has to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to close the connection explicitly in 0.4.x. 0.5.x auto-closes on unsubscribe from the connection input.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question.